# VSCode and PyOpenGL import errors?

Tags: python, opengl, visual-studio-code, python-import

Running this code in normal IDLE is completely fine.

```
import OpenGL.GL as gl
```

However in VSCode, I get an import error.

```
No module named 'OpenGL.GL'; 'OpenGL' is not a package
File "C:\Users\Fluffy\Desktop\OpenGL.py", line 1, in <module>
import OpenGL.GL as gl
File "C:\users\fluffy\desktop\&lt;frozen importlib._bootstrap&gt;", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "C:\users\fluffy\desktop\&lt;frozen importlib._bootstrap_external&gt;", line 678, in exec_module
File "C:\users\fluffy\desktop\&lt;frozen importlib._bootstrap&gt;", line 665, in _load_unlocked
File "C:\users\fluffy\desktop\&lt;frozen importlib._bootstrap&gt;", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "C:\users\fluffy\desktop\&lt;frozen importlib._bootstrap&gt;", line 971, in _find_and_load
File "C:\users\fluffy\desktop\&lt;frozen importlib._bootstrap&gt;", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "C:\users\fluffy\desktop\&lt;frozen importlib._bootstrap&gt;", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "C:\users\fluffy\desktop\&lt;frozen importlib._bootstrap&gt;", line 971, in _find_and_load
File "C:\Users\fluffy\Desktop\OpenGL.py", line 1, in <module>
import OpenGL.GL as gl
```

Furthermore, I uninstalled PyOpenGL and noticed that VSCode's intellisense found an existing OpenGL module within python:
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVDlI.png)

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with VSCode's way of importing modules from python.

NOTE: I tried reinstalling the PyOpenGL in many different ways, the error still persists.

Comment: Maybe you are using incorrect version of python interpreter. Ctrl+Shift+P -> Select Python Interpreter and select the correct version

Comment: Yeah.. but the thing is. I am using the correct interpreter. I installed other modules such as tensorflow and they all work fine. Thank you though.